# Python Stop Read Because Subtitute Character

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a txt file that I want to read in python. But, in that txt file, there is a Subtitute Character in the middle of text. That made reading stop in the middle.

So when I do this:

```
filetxt=open('file.txt')
line=filetxt.read()
print line
```

It only show some first character until the position of Subtitute Character. Can you help me?

Comment: What is substitute character in your text file ?

Comment: @Bhansa character which encode to number 26 (decimal) in ASCII encoding.

Comment: That's Control-Z, the old DOS End Of File marker. I suppose you're using Windows...

Comment: @PM2Ring yes, I'm using windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file in binary mode

```
file_txt = open('file.txt','rb')
```

Comment: Oh wait... it's working now. It's not working before because I simply didn't write 'wb' for the txt file that I want to write.